# Filtering arrays in PHP by parameter

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I was wondering if theres a way to filter arrays in PHP via doing something like this:

```
if (!in_array("something",$something)
```

Now I'd like to get all the values that are NOT matched by the search criterion.

For instance if I have an array like this:

```
$options = array("Preview", "Live", "Completed");
```

and I pass the value for search: "Preview", I'd like to return these two elements in the array "Live" and "Completed" as a result of my array filtering...

Is there some way I could do this?

Edit:

We have an initial array like this:

```
$options = array("Preview", "Live", "Completed");
```

Initial input to the search of array is "Preview" string.

Output array that I'd like it to be is:

```
$newArray = array("Live", "Completed");
```

EDIT EDIT (WHAT IM ACTUALLY TRYING TO ACHIEVE):

Hi guys this is what I'm actually trying to do:

```
<?php foreach($active_brand as $brand?>
 <select>
                            <?php if (in_array($brand['State'], $options)) { ?>
                                <option selected="selected"  value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?=$brand['State']?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php for($i=1;$i<count($options);$i++) { ?>
                                <option  value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?=array_diff($options, array($brand['State']))[$i]?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                        </select>
<?php }?>
```

As you can see guys, I have a column in my DB which is Called a "State"... It's basically a varchar where I keep my string stored... Brand state can only be the 3 following states:

```
Preview => Live => Completed
```

The first thing I do is set the current value to select list like following:

```
<?php if (in_array($brand['State'], $options)) { ?>
                                    <option selected="selected"  value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?=$brand['State']?></option>
                                <?php }?>
```

Now I have defined an array like this in my phtml file like this:

```
$options = array("Preview", "Live", "Completed");
```

Now I'm simply trying to filter out the states that are not in the array and place them in my select tag like this:

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<count($options);$i++) { ?>
                            <option  value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?=array_diff($options, array($brand['State']))[$i]?></option>
                        <?php }?>
```

So that the structure in my select list is like following:

Current state of brand => defaultly selected => add the two missing states to select list (but not to add the current one that is set in DB)...

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you please add "example input" and "example output"?

Comment: Hi Will I edited my question , can you look into it now ?

Comment: Please show us what you already tried and what is not working

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis I've edited my question, can you look into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$notIn = array_diff($options, array('Preview'));
```

Nice thing about it, is that you can filter with multiple values if you need.

**Update:**

I think, a little bit would be more clear to do the following:

```
<?php foreach($active_brand as $brand) { ?>
<select>
    <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
        <option <?php if($brand['State'] == $option) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?=$brand['id']?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: is there any way I can get a single value thats NOT matched by the search criterion while doing a for loop at the same time ? This seems like a really good solution, just missing what I wrote here... Could this be done ?

Comment: Can you give some more details what you need. I don't quite understand. Also, update your question with that info, because the code above does exactly what you have described: $options = array("Preview", "Live", "Completed"); -> $newArray = array("Live", "Completed"); with search critera "Preview"

Comment: Hi I've edited my question... Can you look into it please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function removeAllValuesMatching(array $arr, $value) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr, $value);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    return $arr;
}

$options = array("Preview", "Live", "Completed");

removeAllValuesMatching($options, "Preview"); // pass array and value to match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter()

```
$array = array('Preview', 'Live', 'Completed');
$blacklist = 'Preview';
$result = array_filter($array, function($value) use ($blacklist) {
    if($value !== $blacklist){
        return $value;
    }
});
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

You can adjust it, so $blacklist can be an array if you need to.